# ThunderboltEX II with Asus Z97-A USB 3.1

Tags: windows, drivers, motherboard, thunderbolt

I've just upgraded my MOBO from ASUS Z97-AR to ASUS Z97-A USB3.1. Everything works fine, as this is basically the same motherboard, however, I am not able to configure and use my ThunderboltEX II card properly.

The thunderbolt card worked flawlessly with my old MOBO, but it is not functioning properly with the new one. I can see the card in the BIOS, but it is not working in Windows 10 64bit.

I have reinstalled all the related drivers, still no success.

> When I try to upgrade the ThunderboltEX II firmware, it says this.
>
> Forcing power to the Thunderbolt controller(s)... The Thunderbolt
>   controller(s) is now powered. Failed to load Thunderbolt(TM)
>   controllers through WMI.
>
> Please click the "Cancel" button to finish the tool.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This message may well mean that you have not enabled the Thunderbolt setting correctly in the Bios (which is oddly necessary despite this being an add-in card).

In The Bios, go to Advanced > Intel Thunderbolt.
set Intel Thunderbolt Technology to 'Enabled'

(If you do not see this, you may need to update your BIOS)

You will need to change AIC Location Group and AIC Location to settings that depend on where you physically installed the card. For me this was:

AIC Location Group: CPU0 NB PCIE Slot
AIC Location: NB PCIE X16_2

now save those settings and reboot. If this has worked for you the Thunderbolt items on the system tray should react to newly installed devices.

The above applied on my ASUS Z170-A also with a ThunderboltEX II Dual and getting that to work with a Focusrite Clarett Pre 8 X device.

I'm back here to answer this because this question gave me hope when I too was stuck, Good Luck.

Comment: No luck for me :/ What're the rest of your settings? I've tried adjusting just about everything with no success.

Comment: May be worth setting everything to default and then adding the AIC Location Group.
Is your Thunderbolt card actually on that slot or a different one?

Comment: It's in the 4th slot (CPU/NB controlled for me) and I set it as such.

Comment: The mobo has markings on it for each slot. On mine, the card is in a port marked PCIEX16_2 which is the 5th slot from the top 

Note that the 4th slot the top is PCI not PCIEX.

I'm using Version 2.17.1246 of the bios. HTH

Comment: By 4th slot I meant 4th PCI-e 16x physical slot. I can assure you I have the correct slot set.

Comment: Sounds like your settings are the same as mine. Sorry I can't help more

Answer (score 0):

Here we are 7 or 8 years later. I highly doubt anyone will still be using this combo:

- TB2 audio interface
- Asus mobo Z97-a USB 3.1
- & Asus ThundrrboltEX II card. Especially if you're just starting a build etc.

I built my PC about 7 years ago, and its the same exact board and card that the OP was having issues with (listed above).

Just today, I received a used Presonus TB2 Quantum, and TB2 cable. I was pulling my hair out all day trying to make it work. I was running a USB interface before.

This thread was the first to pop up on a Google search for this issue with the exact setup mentioned above.

As stated, it's unlikely anyone will need this info in 2023, but if you built your PC with this board & TB2 card 7 years ago as I did, and it's still running like a champ, here's what worked for me installing a TB2 audio interface:

- Put TB2 card in **bottom** slot.
- In the BIOS, under the `Advanced` > `Thunderbolt` config, all the TB defaults were already correct. AIC #4 etc. You shouldn't need to change anything there.
- While in `Advanced`, click the header directly **under** the Thunderbolt config one (I already forget what it's called).
- There should be a `USB3.1 line item` option with a drop-down to the right. Its default is set to `USB3.1`.
- Click the drop-down and change it to `Thunderbolt`!

I **guess** the 3.1 and TB2 share a bus, and you can only use one or the other.

Would also be a good idea to not use the 3.1 ports. Not sure why this option isn't available in the TB config settings as well. Really weird.

Anyway, I'm up and running, and just wanted to share in case you're as late to the game as I was with a TB2 interface, along with the mentioned MoBo.

Comment: Hello, please format your answer with some paragraphs/lists/etc. and without random caps locks as it's hardly readable now.

Comment: Is this real? I didn't have much time to type, and wanted to get the details posted while still fresh.                                               -                                                                  I apologize that the grammar doesn't meet your standards.                   -                                                       I was just trying to help anyone with the same challenge, who might find this thread via Google as I did. 
- Ben

Comment: Yes, improvements are real. I don't know what's the purpose of your comment as a reply to a kind request to adjust the formatting (not grammar, which I haven't mentioned anywhere). If you truly want to help, readability matters **a lot**.  Now I see you made your post a lot clearer and more people will benefit from it, so good work.